# how efficiency is calculated and basic understanding of for

Tags: python

**a.** Why the code doesn't print `is prime` for each m in the range that doesn't enter the `if` condition?

```
def trial_division(N):
    up= round(N**0.5+0.5)
    for m in range (2,up+1):
        if N%m==0:
            print (m,"is the smallest divisor of",N) 
            break
    else:
        print (N, "is prime")
```

**b.** How to calculate its efficiency? If `N` is n bits long why it isn't  N<sup>n\2</sup>

Comment: How do bits enter into this?

Comment: the algorithm has N^0.5 stages and thus takes at most N^0.5 divisions, but if N is n bit long what is N^0.5 in terms of n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `else` clause of a `for` loop is only executed after the `for` loop has ended, *unless* a `break` statement was used to abort the loop early.

So the program works as designed: If the `for` loop finishes normally, it means that there was no divisor between 2 and `sqrt(N)`, so `N` is prime.

See it live on [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+trial_division%28N%29%3A%0A++++up%3D+round%28N%2a%2a0.5%2B0.5%29%0A++++for+m+in+range+%282,up%2B1%29%3A%0A++++++++if+N%25m%3D%3D0%3A%0A++++++++++++print+%28m,%22is+the+smallest+divisor+of%22,N%29+%0A++++++++++++break%0A++++else%3A%0A++++++++print+%28N,+%22is+prime%22%29%0A++++++++%0Atrial_division%287%29%0Atrial_division%289%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&curInstr=0).

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker how it shown in the code configuration that else is executed after the for loop has ended?

Comment: @user7777777: It's clear from the indentation. The `else` is clearly on the same indentation level as the `for` statement.

Comment: @  Joel Cornett indentation puts the limits of operation performance ? like { } in Java?

Comment: @user7777777: Yes. That's a fundamental principle of Python.

Comment: @  Tim Pietzcker can else be omitted?

Comment: @user7777777: Not really. If you remove the entire `else` clause (including the `print` that's contained within it), then of course you don't get any output if `N` is prime. If you only remove the line `else:` you get an `IndentationError` because the `print` is indented incorrectly. And if you remove the `else` and outdent the `print`, then the message `N is prime` will *always* be printed...

Comment: @user7777777: Yes. That's what I wrote in the first sentence of my answer. Have you seen [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+trial_division(N)%3A%0A++++up%3D+round(N**0.5%2B0.5)%0A++++for+m+in+range+(2,up%2B1)%3A%0A++++++++if+N%25m%3D%3D0%3A%0A++++++++++++print+(m,%22is+the+smallest+divisor+of%22,N)+%0A++++++++++++break%0A++++else%3A%0A++++++++print+(N,+%22is+prime%22)%0A++++++++%0Atrial_division(7)%0Atrial_division(9)&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&curInstr=0)?

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker in general `else` work with `if` and also with `for`?

Comment: @user7777777: Yes, and with `while`, `try`, and with conditionals (`a = 1 if b==2 else 0`)...you might want to read https://ncoghlan_devs-python-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html

Comment: @  Tim Pietzcke May you  gave a recommendation about  books or websites about python 3 , complexity of a recursive algorithm, trees ?

Answer (score -3):

How about you force the float to an integer because the range method takes in integers

```
 def trial_division(N):
     up= round(N**0.5+0.5)
     for m in range(2,int(up+1)):
        if m%2 == 0:
            print (m, "is the smallest divisor of",N) 
            break
        else:
            print (N, 'is prime')

 trial_division(4)
```

Comment: python sees it as a float since it has the .0 end like 2.0 is a float and that it what it returns but the range requires only ints.

Comment: Not in Python 3; this question is obviously about Python 3 (check the  `print()` function. In Python 2, you would get a tuple representation with this code).